# Can anyone explain this TypeScript statement?

Tags: typescript

I'm a rather newbie for TypeScript.

Can anyone explain the meaning of this TypeScript code snippet?

```
function MappableMixin<T extends Constructor<Model<MappableTraits>>>(Base: T) {
```

Code link is [here](https://github.com/TerriaJS/terriajs/blob/00ee7b242635ff7c4e542c2285f35cae23ee715b/lib/ModelMixins/MappableMixin.ts#L52)

Thanks.

Comment: Which part of the statement is unclear?

Comment: It's a function (mixin) that returns a class of a specific generic type. Do you have a more specific question?

Comment: mostly <T extends Constructor<Model<MappableTraits>>>(Base: T)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's break this down bit by bit:

```
function MappableMixin(Base: T)
```

The function takes a generic type `T` a its argument

```
function MappableMixin<T extends Something>(Base: T)
```

The `<TypeArgument>` term just between the function name and the `(params)` term tells typescript to expect that the return type of this function of of type `TypeArgument`.  In the case that `TypeArgument` is of the form `T extends Something`, it means that the returned value will be a type that extends `Something`, meaning it has all the properties of `Something`.  Essentially in this case, `MappableMixin` takes in some argument, and returns that argument with the extra properties of the type `Something`.

```
<Model<MappableTraits>>
```

This is a generic type with a type argument.  So for example, you may have a type `Model`, which accepts a type as an argument:

```
interface Model<T> {
  thing1: string;
  thing2: T
}
```

In the case of using `<Model<MappableTraits>>`, `Model<T>` would have the type

```
interface Model<MappableTraits> {
  thing1: string;
  thing2: MappableTraits
}
```

So `Constructor<Model<MappableTraits>>>` follows this same pattern, just 2 layers deep.

So the whole phrase means that `MappableMixin` is a function that returns an extended version of the value you gave it. The extension is specifically of the type `Constructor<Model<MappableTraits>>>`, which is a 2-layer typescript generic.

Comment: hi, Seth, thank you very much.